# Poor Performance of CSS Transitions

Tags: html, performance, css-transitions

I am working on a website and I have just modified the navigation bar with more features delivered through CSS transitions.

The resulting performance is unexpectedly low.

What am I doing incorrectly?

[Website in Question](https://www.buzzpoints.com)

Comment: Please provide the minimal, relevant code in your question. See [mcve] and [ask] for information on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has a problem in the app.js file

Record a timeline at the console (f12) to see the warning:

```
Forced synchronous layout is a possible performance bottleneck.
```

[Read more](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/profile-performance/rendering-tools/forced-synchronous-layouts?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I'm going to deep dive into this documentation to be more familiar with the Chrome Development Tools.